# Golang server "write tcp ... use of closed network connection"

Tags: heroku, go, redis

I am beginner at Go, I had wrote small server to testing and deploy it on heroku platform. I have /logout request, which almost works, but sometimes I see something like this:

```
PANIC: write tcp 172.17.110.94:36641->10.11.189.195:9951: use of closed network connection
```

I don't know why it happens, and why sometimes it works perfectly.
My steps:

I send 1st **POST** request to **/token-auth** with body then generate token and send as response. 
At 2nd I do **/logout GET** request with that token, and set token to **Redis store**

Here is full code of my redil_cli.go

```
    package store
import (
    "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"
)

type RedisCli struct {
    conn redis.Conn
}

var instanceRedisCli *RedisCli = nil

func Connect() (conn *RedisCli) {
    if instanceRedisCli == nil {
        instanceRedisCli = new(RedisCli)
        var err error
        //this is works!!!
        instanceRedisCli.conn, err = redis.Dial("tcp", "lab.redistogo.com:9951")

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        if _, err := instanceRedisCli.conn.Do("AUTH", "password"); err != nil {
            //instanceRedisCli.conn.Close()
            panic(err)
        }


    }


    return instanceRedisCli
}

func (redisCli *RedisCli) SetValue(key, value string, expiration ...interface{}) error {
    _, err := redisCli.conn.Do("SET", key, value)

    if err == nil && expiration != nil {
        redisCli.conn.Do("EXPIRE", key, expiration[0])
    }
    return err
}

func (redisCli *RedisCli) GetValue(key string) (interface{}, error) {
    data, err := redisCli.conn.Do("GET", key)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    return data, err
}
```

After that my function that checks Authorization header will panic while trying to do `GetValue(key string)` method

```
func (redisCli *RedisCli) GetValue(key string) (interface{}, error) {
    data, err := redisCli.conn.Do("GET", key)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    return data, err
}
```

Can anyone point me, what I doing wrong?

Comment: the error sounds like the `redisCli.conn` object got closed at some point before `("GET", key)` succeeds

Comment: @Plato, Yes, I understand it, I commented code where I shut it, do you know can heroku close my object?

Comment: You could try passing in high timeouts to Dial: https://github.com/garyburd/redigo/blob/master/redis/conn.go#L128-L146

Comment: Just use a Pool instead of individual connections. There's even an example of auth during connect in the documentation.

Comment: @JimB, I tried it, it seems that heroku closes my connection, because when I deploy my server and first 10 minutes it works, after my request will fail, first log "PANIC: EOF", 2nd try to do request will show log as described above

Comment: So first, don't use panic to handle errors. Then either handle the error and reconnect, try setting IdleTimeout on the Pool to something less than the server's settings in your environment.

Comment: Is there some reason for re-inventing the wheel and not using something like redigo? https://github.com/garyburd/redigo

Comment: FYI i do receive this "use of closed network connection" with redigo, which uses pools. i have max idle connections  set at 10